# Creating time modes for clock application M

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, clock

So for this application, I want to create a clock with four modes.

1. Business time: local time 9:00am – 5:59pm
2. Business overtime: local time 6:00pm – 7:59pm
3. Person time: local time: 8:00am – 8:59am, 8:00pm - 10:59pm
4. Sleeping time: local time: 11:00pm – 7:59am

So based on the time, the icon for the clock will change every time it reach the certain mode.

For example, the color icon for Business time is red while the Business Overtime icon colour is yellow. When the time reach 9 am, the icon on the clock will change to the red icon. And if the time then changes to 6 pm, the icon color will turn into yellow.

Maybe it's just me, but I haven't find any good tutorials or websites that help explain how to create modes like this. Please help. Or redirect me to a link where I can make this mode, that would be great.

It doesn't have to be automatically updating itself.

Thank you.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking.

Comment: I have fix it. Is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds to me like a simple conditional:

```rb
time = Time.current # or Time.now, if you're not using Rails

if time.hour >= 9 && time.hour < 18
  'business'
elsif time.hour >= 18 && time.hour < 20
  'overtime'
elsif (time.hour >= 8 && time.hour < 9) || (time.hour >= 20 && time.hour < 23)
  'person'
else
  'sleeping'
end
```

If you feel like it, you can use ranges instead (note that `...` can be used for a range that includes the initial element but doesn't include the last element, so `18...20` is basically the same as `18..19` – but I think in this case, end-exclusive ranges are clearer):

```rb
time = Time.current # or Time.now, if you're not using Rails

if (9...18).include?(time.hour)
  'business'
elsif (18...20).include?(time.hour)
  'overtime'
elsif time.hour == 8 || (20...23).include?(time.hour)
  'person'
else
  'sleeping'
end
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so smart. Do I put this in the Controller or Helper? Or maybe other files instead?

Comment: Nevermind, I got help for a friend for that. And after few tinkering, the code worked. Thank you.